# How to differentiate a 1-dim array from multi-dim array that have the same count?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have 2 potential responses arrays, that I am not sure which one will I get.
But I know that it will be one of these following:

- 1 - might contain array that has key and value
- 2 - might contain only key and value

My goal is to check to see if my response is falling into one of that category and do my logic base on that.

I tried using PHP `count()` function, but they both return 2 - *which is same value*.

What should I check to know what type of response I am getting?

array#1

```
array:2 [▼

  0 => array:2 [▼

        "content" => "Administrator"
        "XSI:TYPE" => "xs:string"

    ]
      1 => array:2 [▼

        "content" => "Read Only"
        "XSI:TYPE" => "xs:string"

    ]
]
```

array#2

```
array:2 [▼

  "content" => "Read Only"
  "XSI:TYPE" => "xs:string"
]
```

Comment: Sure, the count of those is the same. The first one contains two arrays and the second one contains two strings.

Comment: Have you tried [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: @Don'tPanic : What PHP function to check the different between the 2 ? Do you know ?

Comment: since you know the array keys this would be the fastest way to check `if(isset($myArray['content'])){ } else { }`

Comment: @cmorrissey : ahh !!! brilliant thought ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that way that was [proposed by cmorrissey in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505812/differentiate-an-array-that-have-the-same-count-php/44505975#comment76005311_44505812) seems best:

> since you know the array keys this would be the fastest way to check
>     `if(isset($myArray['content'])){ } else { }`

---

And for a case where you don't know what the array key will be, my previous answer should still work:

Get the first item from the array.

```
$first = reset($array);
```

Then count that.

```
if (count($first) > 1) {
    // it's like array 1
} else {
    // it's like array 2  ( count($any_string) always returns 1 )
}
```

You could also use `is_array($first)`. That might be a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you in differentiating between two arrays of same count. You can use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` flag with [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/815907)

```
if(count($array1,COUNT_RECURSIVE)==count($array2,COUNT_RECURSIVE))
{
    echo "Both's value are strings with equal count";
}
elseif(count($array1,COUNT_RECURSIVE)>count($array2,COUNT_NORMAL))
{
    echo "Array one is array of arrays";
}
else
{
    echo "Array two is array of arrays";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you need to know if there inside an array exist an other array. I have this posible solution.

We could have an array like this way:

```
$array = array(1, "string", array(1, 2));
```

It have an integer, string and an array. We can use gettype() function to get the type of a thing.

In this example:

```
 foreach($array as $row) {
   echo gettype($row) . '<br>';
 }
```

We have the next result:

```
integer
string
array
```

We can do this:

```
foreach($array as $row) {
  if(gettype($row) == 'array') {
    echo "This is an array<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Keep trying guy...<br>";
  }
}
```

And the result gonna be:

```
Keep trying guy...
Keep trying guy...
This is an array
```

I wish this help to you, and remember "Love to code" : )

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question verbatim, but my initial feeling is you mean to check if the parent array has any child array elements?

In that case, I think you mean?

```
foreach ($response as $element) {

    if (is_array($element)) {
        // The element is an array
    } else {
        // The element is not an array
    }
}
```